# "Not available: couldn't connect to your application" live metrics Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have web application in .Net Framework 4.7.2. It deployed as App service in Azure. I have enable Application Insights in it. And I can read logs. But when I click on "Live metrics", It shows "Not available: couldn't connect to your application"
[image]

I have added latest packages of "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" in application. Also in azure portal, in that app service, app settings "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING" added in configuration.

Also I check Microsoft troubleshoot article "Troubleshoot couldn't connect to your application" but steps which mention in that article are already followed.

I am not able to find reason why it could not connect to application. Can someone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

***When you create the App Service in the Azure Portal, it will also create the App Insights Resource as well***:

[image]

You have to connect the Web Application to the associated App Insights Resource before publishing the Web Site:
[image]

When you run the Web Application (Open the URL), then the Request Rate, Time will be shown in the Live Metrics. As you can see in below Gifs it is showing the Request Rate, Time when I refresh the home page:

[image]

[image]

**Note:**

1. Check you have the packages related to Application Insights in `Web.Config` File > Under Configuration Section:

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

**Packages.config file code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.22.0-beta1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.4.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.22.0-beta1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.22.0-beta1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.22.0-beta1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.22.0-beta1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.22.0-beta1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="4.1.0-preview1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Buffers" version="4.5.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Memory" version="4.5.5" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Numerics.Vectors" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="7.0.0-preview.2.22152.2" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/live-stream) for more information.